# How to restore a partition after messing up fstab?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

My laptop would not boot

`integrity: problem loading x.509 certificate -65`

I looked up on the internet and found out that my hard disk could be broken. After testing it with a live flash drive it seemed to be working so I tried to reinstall Ubuntu only formatting the OS partition so I could keep my files.

Went fine, at this point I had this partition `sda1` where I had my stuff. I was using `mount --bind /username /home/username` to mount and bind `sda1` with the home directory. Because it would not remain like that after a reboot I looked for something to make it permanent.
I added the following to the `fstab` and rebooted.

```
UUID=288a84bf-876c-4c4b-a4ba-d6b4cc6fc0d2  /mnt/device            ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail   0       2
/mnt/device                                /srv/binded_device     none    bind                      0       0
```

What happened is that it would fail after the login so I was stuck in a loop where I could not get past the login screen. I managed to edit the `fstab` again, comment the new lines and reboot. After rebooting again I opened the Disk app and saw that the files I kept (`sda1`, that partition I tried to mount) is now titled as unknown not `sda1`. By this I mean that I could not mount it neither from Disk neither from Files->Other Locations.

[Disk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfMg3.png)

Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 223,58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SUV500M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x25b15a76

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048    976895    974848   476M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb2       215822334 245116927  29294594    14G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb3          976896 215820287 214843392 102,5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb5       215822336 245116927  29294592    14G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? what exactly did you try from the forum? how did you determine that the partition is now unallocated?

Comment: Where is your "old home"? Which partition? What do you mean by "unallocated"?

Comment: You could have mounted as `/home` during the install, and UNcheck the "format" box.

Comment: @ohpleasework please [edit] this information into your question

Comment: @waltinator I did not think of that, by old home i mean the partition i did not format when reinstalling ubuntu. When i mounted it with ```mount --bind /username /home/username``` it was titled sda1, after the attempt in fstab it appeared as unkown in Disks. Now i notice it says unkown, not unallocated, my bad.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]